# ValueError: Generator yielding element of unexpected shape when using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator().padded_batch() - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, valueerror

I am trying to train a named entity recognition model using tensorflow (version 2.2.0). I have been adapting [this model](https://github.com/guillaumegenthial/tf_ner/blob/master/models/chars_conv_lstm_crf/main.py) to tensorflow 2. This model utilises `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` and the `.padded_batch` attribute to efficiently stream the training data from disk. However, I keep recieving errors relating to the shape of the data being outputted by the generator.

Here is my code for my generator functions and the function that wraps it into a `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`:

```
# python 3.7.7
import tensorflow as tf

tf.__version__
# 2.2.0

def generator(sent_file, tag_file):
    with open(sent_file, "r") as sents, open(tag_file, "r") as tags:
        for line_sents, line_tags in zip(sents, tags):
            yield parser(line_sents, line_tags)

def parser(line_sents, line_tags):
    # Words and tags.
    words = [w.encode() for w in line_sents.strip("\n").split()]
    tags = [t.encode() for t in line_tags.strip("\n").split()]

    # Characters.
    chars = [[c.encode() for c in w] for w in line_sents.strip("\n").split()]
    lengths = [len(c) for c in chars]
    max_len = max(lengths)
    chars = [c + [b"<pad>"] * (max_len - 1) for c, l in zip(chars, lengths)]

    # breakpoint()   # BREAKPOINT 1

    return ((words, len(words)), (chars, lengths)), tags


def inputter(wordpath, tagpath, params=None, shuffle_and_repeat=False):
    params = params if params is not None else {}

    shapes = (((tf.TensorShape(dims=[None]), tf.TensorShape(dims=())),  # words, num_words
               (tf.TensorShape(dims=[None, None]), tf.TensorShape(dims=[None]))),
              tf.TensorShape(dims=[None]))  # tags

    types = (((tf.string, tf.int32),
              (tf.string, tf.int32)),
             tf.string)

    defaults = ((('<pad>', 0),
                 ('<pad>', 0)),
                'O')

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator=generator,
        output_shapes=shapes,
        output_types=types,
        args=(wordpath, tagpath)
    )

    # breakpoint()   # BREAKPOINT 2.

    if shuffle_and_repeat:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(params['buffer']).repeat(params['epochs'])

    dataset = (dataset
               .padded_batch(params.get('batch_size', 20),
                             padded_shapes=shapes,
                             padding_values=defaults)
               )

    # breakpoint()   # BREAKPOINT 3.

    return dataset
```

When I get to the  `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` line of my script, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (29,) where an element of shape (None, None) was expected.
```

I inserted breakpoints to debug my script at the three commented-out `breakpoint()` lines.

At breakpoint 1, inside the `parser` function, the values to be returned appear correct and match the rank/dimensions specified in the `output_shapes` argument of `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`:

```
# (Pdb) words
[b'No', b'association', b'was', b'also', b'found', b'in', b'European', b'and', b'Asian', b'individuals', b'hospital', b'based', b'controls', b'ever', b'smoking', b'subjects', b'DM', b'assessment', b'by', b'medical', b'record', b'or', b'physician', b'diagnosis', b'and', b'insulin', b'prescription', b'for', b'DM']

# (Pdb) len(words)
29

# (Pdb) chars
[[b'N', b'o', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'a', b's', b's', b'o', b'c', b'i', b'a', b't', b'i', b'o', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'w', b'a', b's', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'a', b'l', b's', b'o', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'f', b'o', b'u', b'n', b'd', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'i', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'E', b'u', b'r', b'o', b'p', b'e', b'a', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'a', b'n', b'd', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'A', b's', b'i', b'a', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'i', b'n', b'd', b'i', b'v', b'i', b'd', b'u', b'a', b'l', b's', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'h', b'o', b's', b'p', b'i', b't', b'a', b'l', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'b', b'a', b's', b'e', b'd', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'c', b'o', b'n', b't', b'r', b'o', b'l', b's', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'e', b'v', b'e', b'r', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b's', b'm', b'o', b'k', b'i', b'n', b'g', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b's', b'u', b'b', b'j', b'e', b'c', b't', b's', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'D', b'M', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'a', b's', b's', b'e', b's', b's', b'm', b'e', b'n', b't', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'b', b'y', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'm', b'e', b'd', b'i', b'c', b'a', b'l', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'r', b'e', b'c', b'o', b'r', b'd', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'o', b'r', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'p', b'h', b'y', b's', b'i', b'c', b'i', b'a', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'd', b'i', b'a', b'g', b'n', b'o', b's', b'i', b's', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'a', b'n', b'd', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'i', b'n', b's', b'u', b'l', b'i', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'p', b'r', b'e', b's', b'c', b'r', b'i', b'p', b't', b'i', b'o', b'n', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'f', b'o', b'r', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>'], [b'D', b'M', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>', b'<pad>']]

# (Pdb) lengths
[2, 11, 3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 3, 5, 11, 8, 5, 8, 4, 7, 8, 2, 10, 2, 7, 6, 2, 9, 9, 3, 7, 12, 3, 2]

# (Pdb) tags
[b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'O', b'B', b'O', b'O', b'O']
```

At breakpoint 2, inside the `inputter` function immedeately after the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` is created, the shape of the dataset is, as expected:

```
# (Pbd) dataset.element_spec
(((TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), (TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None))
```

At breakpoint 3, after `.padded_batch` is called, each nested element of the dataset has increased in rank by 1, accounting for the batch size?

```
# (Pdb) dataset.element_spec
(((TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), (TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))), TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.string, name=None))
```

Can anyone please help me to understand what is going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: from document : .padded_batch function (like tf.data.Dataset.batch) the components of the resulting element will have an additional outer dimension,

Comment: Thank you! You helped me to go in the right direction. In the end I mapped the dataset using a function that converted the tuple structure into a named dictionary. I used this to explicitly pass the padding_shape using a dictionary of feature shapes.

Comment: I thought I had fixed the error, but it is still occurring

Comment: in the line : chars = [c + [b"<pad>"] * (max_len - 1) for c, l in zip(chars, lengths)] , (max_len - 1) or (max_len - l)  ?

Comment: This is so embarrassing haha! That fixed it! I've been looking at these lines of code for days and I couldn't see that haha Thank you so much! My hero!

Comment: I'm so happy to help you, Does that fix the bug?

Comment: could you select it as the correct answer,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code , 1 instead of l ;change the line :

```
 chars = [c + [b"<pad>"] * (max_len - 1) for c, l in zip(chars, lengths)] ,
```

to :

```
 chars = [c + [b"<pad>"] * (max_len - l) for c, l in zip(chars, lengths)] ,
```